# Get only categories with news

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm building a rails app. and i wanted to know if there is an automatic way to get only categories with news on it.

if i want to make a list on a side bar, but only show categories for public filter?

---

Hi, i'm new on this, and i have this code:

products with: - brand_id - category_id

i just want to: when i enter into a brand, then show just categories with products of that brand.

i asume is like this:

```
brand.products.find(:all)
```

this wil show me all products with `brand_id` where i am

and, how can i make this for category + brand?

```
brand.category.products(:all)
```

will not result, i'm a bit confused

then

Comment: we need ask to close it. We are two of ask this closed

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO and please read the faq.  You can update your question by editing it; it is the preferred way of adding more information.  Also, you've created two accounts; I've merged them, but please watch out for that in future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need code it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a query, or a quick way is to use:

```
category.news.size != 0
```

since `category.news` will return an array of news entries that has that category, so if size is 0, then don't show it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.find(
  :all,
  :select => 'posts.*, count(categories.id) as category_count',
  :joins  => 'left outer join categories on categories.post_id = posts.id',
  :group  => 'posts.id',
  :having => 'category_count > 0'
)
```